# Find the first non-repeated character in a string using C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am working to solve this problem. I have to find the first nonrepeated character in a string.

For example, 
      Input : “teeter”
      Output: r

I am going to first use HashTables :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var inputString =  “teeter” ;
        Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
        int numb = 1; 
        for (int i=0; i< inputString.length(); i++)
        {   
             if (!hashtable.ContainsKey(hashtable[i])) 
                 hashtable.Add(hashtable[i], numb);
             else  
                 hashtable[hashtable[i]] = hashtable[i].Value+ 1 ;
        }
    }
}
```

Can I solve this problem using LinQ:

```
numb = inputString.First(1 == inputString.Where(item => 
                              item == hashtable[i]).Count());
```

My questions are :

-I have to solve this problem using LINQ and using HashTables or Dictionaries. Does my solutions ture ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Asking for the "best" solution is highly subjective and leads to extended discussion.  Change your question to ask a specific question.  Then make up your own mind, given your requirements, as to which is the better approach.

Comment: True! I will compare the both after implementing it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logic to get the first non-repeating(distinct) character from the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994644/logic-to-get-the-first-non-repeatingdistinct-character-from-the-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need `HashTable` at all. Because `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>` you can use LINQ directly on your input string:

```
var letter = input.GroupBy(x => x).First(g => g.Count() == 1).Key;
```

Getting back to your *`HashTable`* solution. You 're not using it correctly. `HashTable` is not the same as `Dictionary`. It does not have `key`/`value`, it just has `key`s. You're looking for `Dictionary` here:

```
var inputString =  "teeter";
var dict = new Dictionary<char, int>();
int numb = 1; 
for (int i=0; i< inputString.length(); i++)
{   
     if (!dict.ContainsKey(inputString[i])) 
         dict.Add(inputString[i], numb);
     else  
         dict[inputString[i]] += 1;
}
```

Comment: But the question is about solving this problem using different strategies ?

Comment: I got inspired by this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3

Comment: Your program work ! Can you point me to a good article for the use of HashTables and Dictionaries in .Net ? 'cause this last one is special case of HashTables but generic

Comment: Yes, it's generic dictionary. I don't really think you should even consider using non-generic ones.

Comment: Here: Shouldn't be dict[inputString[i]].value += 1 ; as we are modefing the "Int" value ; How should access to that second attribute

Answer (score 4):

```
// throws an ArgumentNullException if s is null.
// throws an InvalidOperationException if there is no non repeating character.
char FirstNonRepeater(string s)
{
    return s.ToLookup(c => c).First(g => g.Count() == 1).Key;
}
```

Comment: @Stanislav I think the call to `Key` would be faster since the underlying `IGrouping<char, char>` will hold the char in memory instead of forcing an enumeration of the values to get the first one.

Answer (score 1):

For a solution without HashTables, Dictionaries or LINQ, just remove duplicate characters from the string:

```
while (s.IndexOf(s[0], 1) != -1) {
  s = s.Replace(s[0].ToString(), "");
}
char result = s[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check which characters are occured only once, and take first one out of these.

```
var inputString =  “teeter” ;
var output = inputString.GroupBy(x=>x).FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Count() ==1).Key;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
    {
       public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(FirstNonRepeated("tether"));
           Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static char? FirstNonRepeated(string word)
        {
           char[] chararray= word.ToCharArray();
            Hashtable hashtable=new Hashtable();
            foreach (var c in chararray)
            {
                if (hashtable.ContainsKey(c))
                {
                    hashtable[c]=(int)hashtable[c]+1;
                }
                else
                {
                    hashtable.Add(c,1);
                }
            }
            foreach (var v in chararray)
            {
                if ((int) hashtable[v] == 1)
                {
                    return v;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }


    }
```