# How to output unique symbols except case c# without LINQ

Tags: c#

Output unique symbols ignoring case

```
IDictionary<char, int> charDict = new Dictionary<char, int>();

foreach (var ch in text)
{
    if (!charDict.TryGetValue(ch, out n)) {
        charDict.Add(new KeyValuePair<char, int>(ch, 1));
    } else
    {
        charDict[ch]++;
    }
}
```

> **Appellodppsafs** => **Apelodsf**

And Is it possible not to use LINQ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you remove duplicate characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588774/how-can-you-remove-duplicate-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: Beytan Kurt , no, my program need to output unique symbols except case! and without using LINQ

Answer (score 1):

Use a `HashSet<char>` to remember existing characters (that's what `Distinct()` does internally)

Assuming your input and expected result are type `string`

```
string input = "Appellodppsafs";
HashSet<char> crs = new HashSet<char>();
string result = string.Concat(input.Where(x => crs.Add(char.ToLower(x)))); //Apelodsf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (if you do not have long strings or performance issues):

```
string str = "Appellodppsafs";

string result = string.Concat(str.Select(s => $"{s}")
                               .Distinct(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output:

> Apelodsf

Comment: In case of `Distinct()` you can't guarentee the right order of the characters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734852/does-c-sharp-distinct-method-keep-original-ordering-of-sequence-intact

Comment: Well, the correctness depends how OP will use the result.