# How can we remove word with repeated single character?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove word with single repeated characters using regex in python, for example :

```
good => good
gggggggg => g
```

What I have tried so far is following

```
re.sub(r'([a-z])\1+', r'\1', 'ffffffbbbbbbbqqq')
```

Problem with above solution is that it changes `good to god` and I just want to remove words with single repeated characters.

Comment: Why don't you want the `o` in `good` turn into `god`?

Comment: What do you mean by `single repeated character` ? `o` is repeated in `good` hence it is replaced

Comment: See [Python: Best Way to remove duplicate character from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799036/python-best-way-to-remove-duplicate-character-from-string). And as for `good`, regex is not aware of natural language spelling, you should add exceptions yourself.

Comment: I don't want good to be replaced because it is a actual dictionary word

Comment: You can't use regex to determine if a word is in the dictionary. This is impossible.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: But where is your lookup dictionary defined?

Comment: What I mean is that I want to remove word with just single repeated character. like `mmmmmm => m` `aaaaaaa => a`

Comment: so words with more than one character, irrespective of them being repeated or not will be untouched?

Comment: Yes this is what I meant.

Comment: Got it, you can use a set here which will be much simpler, check my answer below @HrithikPuri

Comment: Actually I was looking for something in regex. If possible

Comment: Sure, I have added a regex solution as well @HrithikPuri but I would say do something simpler using a set instead of a regex

Comment: Words consisting of single letter only [like this](https://regex101.com/r/LcqQOJ/2)? Just add [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to your pattern.

Comment: Good point @bobblebubble Do you mind if I put that in my answer referring your comment?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh please add but it's just a guess =)

Comment: Yes, a word boundary or a start and end of string marker should do the job

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better approach here is to use a `set`

```
def modify(s):

    #Create a set from the string
    c = set(s)

    #If you have only one character in the set, convert set to string
    if len(c) == 1:
        return ''.join(c)
    #Else return original string
    else:
        return s

print(modify('good'))
print(modify('gggggggg'))
```

If you want to use regex, mark the start and end of the string in our regex by `^` and `$` (inspired from @bobblebubble comment)

```
import re

def modify(s):

    #Create the sub string with a regex which only matches if a single character is repeated
    #Marking the start and end of string as well
    out = re.sub(r'^([a-z])\1+$', r'\1', s)
    return out

print(modify('good'))
print(modify('gggggggg'))
```

The output will be

```
good
g
```

Comment: Sweet approach with a `set`!

Answer (score 2):

You can use trim command:

take a look at this examples:

```
"ggggggg".Trim('g');
```

Update:
and for characters which are in the middle of the string use this function, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588839/11602664)

**in java:**

```
public static string RemoveDuplicates(string input)
{
    return new string(input.ToCharArray().Distinct().ToArray());
}
```

**in python:**

```
used = set()
unique = [x for x in mylist if x not in used and (used.add(x) or True)]
```

but I think all of these answers does not match situation like `aaaaabbbbbcda`, this string has an a at the end of string which does not appear in the result `(abcd)`. for this kind of situation use this functions which I wrote:

**In:**

```
def unique(s):
    used = set()
    ret = list()
    s = list(s)
    for x in s:
        if x not in used:
            ret.append(x)
            used = set()

        used.add(x)

    return ret

print(unique('aaaaabbbbbcda'))
```

**out:**

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a']
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the contribution but I don't want to trim just 'g'.

Comment: This is Java ? But the question is tagged python

Comment: I add the python code and also correct some incorrect answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use a `set` in your method, this should do the trick:

```
def simplify(s):
  l = len(s)
  if l>1 and s.count(s[0]) == l:
    return s[0]
  return s

print(simplify('good'))
print(simplify('abba'))
print(simplify('ggggg'))
print(simplify('g'))
print(simplify(''))
```

**output:**

```
good
abba
g
g
```

**Explanations:**

- You compute the length of the string
- you count the number of characters that are equal to the first one and you compare the count with the initial string length
- depending on the result you return the first character or the whole string